# How to add to SQL Server by using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm a beginner programmer to try to learn programming.
I just want to write code as simple as possible to add some data to SQL Server from html example below for purpose to learn the flow.

can anybody teach me the simple code by using asp.net?

```
<html>
<head>
<title> user register practice </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>User Register</h1>

ID: <input type = "text"><br/>
Password: <input type = "password"><br/>
name: <input type = "text"><br/>

<input type ="submit">
<input type ="reset">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does it **not work** ?? It's just not adding any data? It's giving you an error ?? If so: **what** is the error???

Answer (score 1):

Your query has syntax errors, it should be `INSERT INTO tablename (fields) VALUES (values)`. You're missing `into`.

Comment: I believe the `INTO` is optional.....see [MSDN docs on INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)